# do you say "walk sloppily" to express someone who walks in a tired or lazy manner.?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Ok, a person may walk like this

-He may slouch

-He may tilt his body from side to side while walking

-He may arch his back forward or backward while walking.

-He may look down at the ground, or up into the sky while walking

-He may be tired or bored or a lazy kind of person.

Do we say "**please walk up straight, don't walk sloppily**"?

**Note:** The person may not be drunk

Comment: From checking the *corpora*, few people do, but it does appear in print. Related to "sloppy drunk," I suppose.

Comment: @user105719, the person may not be drunk

Comment: You need not be drunk to exhibit some symptoms of drink. Just as long as you're aware of the word association